# Xcode programmatically Loading Different ViewControllers in AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

This question might be a repost, but I've looked through similar questions and they all seem outdated. I am new to Xcode and iPhone app development. I have different rootViewControllers that I want to load. One on the first use of the app, and then a regular one. So far, here is the code I have set up:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    // app already launched
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    // This is the first launch ever
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how I can navigate to the initial ViewController, because whenever I do, it doesn't work. The app always breaks at a different line of code in one of my other ViewControllers that has nothing to do with this. Although, when I test it again, it works, because the Bool was set to YES.

So basically, how would I be able to set the rootViewController programmatically, because in the storyboard, I already have it set to the main ViewController I want to load each time, except for the first time the app is opened.

Please provide sample code, as I am not that good of a coder (I am new). The first view controller that I am trying to load in the "else" section is called ViewController and the normal one that I want loading is called a Tab Bar Controller (2 Views in a tab).

Please don't mark this question as a duplicate, because although I have seen some answers, none of them seem to work in Xcode 6 on iOS 8.

Comment: Do you use storyboard?

Comment: Yes I use storyboard

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    // app already launched
    self.window.rootViewController = //your ViewController 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    // This is the first launch ever

    self.window.rootViewController = //your ViewController 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

it help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIViewController *rootVC = nil;
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
        // app already launched
        rootVC = [YourFirstVC alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        // This is the first launch ever
        rootVC = [YourSecondVC alloc] init];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController =  rootVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Also there is a good practice to store keys in static strings like:

```
static NSString *const kHasLaunchedOnce = @"HasLaunchedOnce";
```

It keeps you from problems when you have a typo in a key name.

Comment: 2015-03-12 09:23:05.208 Steinway Family Dental Center[11623:353106] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch. - I got an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])

{

    // app already launched

}
      else

{


 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


 UIViewController *yourVc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yourVc];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    // This is the first launch ever
}
```

`}`

Answer (score 0):

First remove the Storyboard Entry Point from Main.storyboard. Shown in the picture

[image]

Then you need to instantiate proper view controller in App delegate didFinishLaunching function.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *rootViewController = nil;
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    // app already launched
    rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegularViewController"];
}
else
{
    // This is the first launch ever
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VirginViewController"];
}

self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Keep in mind. You need to change the viewcontroller identifiers. (RegularViewController,VirginViewController)

Answer (score -1):

Change this line to whatever color you want in your app.

`self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

For white color,

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```